# Multiple where in one query

Tags: sql

I have table with the following columns

```
id, money, date
```

I want a SQL query that returns the `sum(amount)` calculated between two custom dates like

```
     Date between '2014-1-10' and '2016-3-12' 
     Date between '2015-8-10' and '2017-6-12' 
     Date between '2014-2-10' and '2016-6-12'
```

The result will be some thing similar to

```
customWhere    amount
1             20000000$
2             23495000$
3             12940593$
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: SO is not a query writing service..  I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far

Comment: @MegaTron i have problem with it .. i simplified  question . .. if you can answer it

Comment: First, I want to see what you've done so far to solve the problem

Comment: @MegaTron Select
     sum(Trans_Amount) as amount,
     Trans_Date as Trans_Date
     
from
     Sandogh_Transaction
where 
trans_Date between '2014-10-10' and '2016-10-12'
group by
     Trans_Date       // then i was looking for some thing that allow me to add in group by

Comment: Ok, great. Now please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. See [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MegaTron Is there a link on try posted solution.  It took me three comments to get him to even try my (working) solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  select 1 as cn, sum(amount) as sss 
  from table 
  where Date between '2014-1-10' and '2016-3-12'  
union  
  select 2 as cn, sum(amount) as sss 
  from table
  where Date between '2015-8-10' and '2017-6-12' 
...
```

Comment: Better?  What makes you think this is a bad solution?  Does it work?  Does it have performance problem?

Comment: more than 100 union will have performance problem . what you think ?

Comment: You tell me.   Does it have performance problem?   Show some effort.  Do you have something better?

Answer (score 0):

use a `select case` in the `groupby` clause

```
Select  (select case 
        when MyDate between Convert(date,'Some Date') 
                    and Convert(date,'Other Date')  
        then 1 else 2 end) 'Case', 
        SUM(Ammount) 'Sum'
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY (select case 
        when MyDate between Convert(date,'Some Date') 
                    and Convert(date,'Other Date')  
        then 1 else 2 end)
```

Group By - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Case - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Did you test?  Are sure that will work with overlapping date ranges?

Comment: @Frisbee, you're correct the overlapping breaks it. This would require a temp table or nested query to establish the groups with a name of some sort and would then join to the main table to sum the amount.

Comment: You might want to edit out where criticized the user for what have the tried.  A temp join would create double counts.   Union is the way to do this.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to double count based on the overlapping dates. If I have a value in the overlap between ranges wouldn't I want it counted in both? I don't see how the join double counts differently than the union.

Comment: Not that kind of double.   3 X 4 = 12